# this function should do sorting by relative difference with the integer K {k=7 like [3,6,9] _->[6,9,3]} but its not working

Tags: java, sorting

this function should do sorting by relative difference with the integer K {k=7 like [3,6,9] _->[6,9,3]} but its not working

```
static void sortABS(int arr[], int n,int k)
    {
        
         List al = Arrays.asList(arr);
         Comparator<Integer>com=(a,b)->
        {
          return Math.abs(a-k)-Math.abs(b-k) ;
        };
        Collections.sort(al,com);
        for(int i=1;i<al.size();i++)
          System.out.print(al.get(i)+"");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(arr);` returns a List of `int[]`. That means `Collections.sort` doesn't do anything, because its input contains only one element.

The result printing for-loop at the end is implemented incorrectly, because its index starts at 1 instead of 0. It's also unnecessary, because you can just pass the list `al` directly to `System.out.print`.

The parameter `int n` is unnecessary/unused too.

```
    static void sortABS(int arr[], int k) {
        List<Integer> al = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Comparator<Integer> com = (a, b) -> {
            return Math.abs(a - k) - Math.abs(b - k);
        };
        Collections.sort(al, com);
        System.out.print(al);
    }
```

If you want to avoid the array-to-list conversion and sort the array directly, then you have to use `Integer` instead of `int`.

```
    static void sortABS(Integer arr[], int k) {
        Comparator<Integer> com = (a, b) -> {
            return Math.abs(a - k) - Math.abs(b - k);
        };
        Arrays.sort(arr, com);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

Comment: can i directly sort the array instead of making it list using Arrays.sort method

Comment: @DEBANJANGHOSH Yes, but you probably have to use `Integer` instead of `int`.